# Javascript how to see if "$this" contains a certain ID

Tags: javascript, this

I want to check if the object that a user clicks on in a webpage contains a certain id.

I've tried .includes, .contains, .hasOwnProperty('val'), and a couple others, but no luck.

If the object contains #demo-id-name, then it should fire the code below it.

So I have this in my code, and I want to make it so that if the user clicks on this first

tag, i want to use javascript to check if the clicked object has the "#demo-id-name".

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";
  $(".demo-class").on("click",
    function(event) {
      var $this = $(this);
      if ($this.hasAttribute('#demo-id-name')) {

        /// redacted for brevity etc etc
        clickSpark.fireParticles($(this));
      }
    }):
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="demo-class" id="demo-id-name">something </p>
<p class="demo-class">something ELSE </p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.matches` to check to see if an element matches a particular selector, no need to convert `this` to a `jQuery` collection first:

```js
$(".demo-class").on("click", function() {
  if (this.matches('#demo-id-name')) console.log('match');
  else console.log('no match');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="demo-class" id="demo-id-name">something </p>
<p class="demo-class">something ELSE </p>
```

It's not needed, but if you *do* want to wrap `this` in jQuery first, you can use the [`is`](http://api.jquery.com/is/) method:

```js
$(".demo-class").on("click", function() {
  if ($(this).is('#demo-id-name')) console.log('match');
  else console.log('no match');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="demo-class" id="demo-id-name">something </p>
<p class="demo-class">something ELSE </p>
```

Comment: Thank you for an awesome illuminating answer. I learned a lot from this and I appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

Has Attribute is for detecting if the element has a specific attribute type like `name`, `class` or `id`. not for figuring out the contents of an attribute which ever one that might be.

Just simply grab the name of the elements id attribute and test to see if it matches what you are looking for in an if statement like so.

Also a side note regarding your use of `event`. since you are not using event in your function it's not needed.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  "use strict";

  $(".demo-class").on("click", function() {
    var $this = $(this),
      name = $this.attr('id');
    if (name === 'demo-id-name') {
      alert('WOOOOOO');
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<p class="demo-class" id="demo-id-name">something </p>
<p class="demo-class">something ELSE </p>
```

Answer (score 1):

**JS Code:**

```
 $(".demo-class").on("click",
    function(event) {
      if (this.id.match('demo-id-name')){
                    console.log('ID is matched');
            }
    else {
       console.log('Id is not matched');
    }
            });


<p class="demo-class" id="demo-id-name">something </p>
<p class="demo-class">something ELSE </p>
```

[JSFiddle:](https://jsfiddle.net/wBbdJ/67/)